# Preencher coluna de um data frame com dados de outro data frame no R

Tags: r

Tenho o seguinte df (dados1):

```
ITEM    CLASSIFICACAO
123     AZUL
456     AMARELO
789 
234     VERDE
345     PRETO
456 
567 
678     ROSA
```

Necessito preencher as linhas em branco da coluna `CLASSIFICACAO` utilizando outro data frame (dados2):

```
ITEM    CLASSIFICACAO
789     LARANJA
456     MARROM
567     BRANCO
100     CASA
200     BOLA
```

Como faço para preencher as linhas em branco do df (dados_1)? Grato

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eu faria isso usando o pacote `dplyr`. Com o `dplyr` você vai combinando operações simples até atingir o resultado que você deseja:

Primeiro, os bancos de dados:

```
dados1 <- data.frame(
  ITEM = c(123,456,789,234,345,456,567,678),
  CLASSIFICACAO = c("AZUL", "AMARELO", NA, "VERDE", "PRETO", NA, NA, "ROSA"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
dados2 <- data.frame(
  ITEM = c(789, 456, 567, 100, 200),
  CLASSIFICACAO = c("LARANJA", "MARROM", "BRANCO", "CASA", "BOLA"), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Agora vamos lá:

```
dados1 %>% 
  filter(is.na(CLASSIFICACAO)) %>% # pegamos só as linhas vazias
  select(-CLASSIFICACAO) %>% # tiramos a variável classificação
  left_join(dados2, by = "ITEM") %>% # fazemos o join com o outro bd
  bind_rows(dados1 %>% filter(!is.na(CLASSIFICACAO))) # empilhamos os dois
```

Answer (score 4):

O ideal seria você ter disponibilizado seu banco de dados (através da função `dput`), ou uma parte dele pelo menos.

Com esse exemplo que você passou, caso essas linhas em branco sejam `NA`, você pode utilizar a função `FillIn` do pacote `DataCombine`.

```
dados1 <- data.frame(
  ITEM = c(123,456,789,234,345,456,567,678),
  CLASSIFICACAO = c("AZUL", "AMARELO", NA, "VERDE", "PRETO", NA, NA, "ROSA"))
dados2 <- data.frame(
  ITEM = c(789,456,567,100,200),
  CLASSIFICACAO = c("LARANJA", "MARROM", "BRANCO", "CASA", "BOLA"))

DataCombine::FillIn(dados1, dados2, Var1 = "CLASSIFICACAO", Var2 = "CLASSIFICACAO",
                    KeyVar = "ITEM")

  ITEM CLASSIFICACAO
1  123          AZUL
2  234         VERDE
3  345         PRETO
4  456       AMARELO
5  456        MARROM
6  567        BRANCO
7  678          ROSA
8  789       LARANJA
```

Answer (score 3):

Aqui um outro exemplo com um código que nao utiliza dependencias (somente com o base do R).

No seu exemplo, 456 é o mesmo código usado para AMARELO e MARROM. Eu criei um outro código (457 para MARROM) para evitar duplicados (mas nao sei se essa era sua intenção).

Primeiro defino a regra para completar os dados faltantes com um "match" dos NAs em df1 que por ventura estejam presentes em df2. E logo aplico a regra sobre o data.frame df1

```
df1 <- data.frame(ITEM = c(123,456,789,234,345,457,567,678),
             CLASS = c("AZUL","AMARELO",NA,"VERDE","PRETO",NA,NA,"ROSA"), 
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df2 <- data.frame(ITEM = c(457, 567,100,200, 789),
              CLASS = c("MARROM","BRANCO","CASA","BOLA","LARANJA"), 
              stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

r <- match(df1[is.na(df1$CLASS), "ITEM"], df2$ITEM)

df1[is.na(df1$CLASS), "CLASS" ] <- df2[r, "CLASS"]

print(df1)

  ITEM   CLASS
1  123    AZUL
2  456 AMARELO
3  789 LARANJA
4  234   VERDE
5  345   PRETO
6  457  MARROM
7  567  BRANCO
8  678    ROSA
```